# How to read csv file into a 2-D array in map reduce

Tags: java, mapreduce

```
public class samReducer extends Reducer<Text, callingFunction, Text, Text> {
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<callingFunction> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterator<callingFunction> iterator = values.iterator();
        String toPass = "";
        int i = 0;
        String tmp[] = new String[300];
        //String temp = "";
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
             /*toPass = iterator.next().toString()+ " ";
            context.write(key , new Text((toPass)));*/
            tmp[i++] = iterator.next().toString();
            //i++;
        }
        for(i=0; i<300; i++)
            context.write(key, new Text(tmp[i]));
    }
}
```

I want to use it for back propagation algorithm in map reduce.

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan, I've approved your edit, but be careful about the indentation, you need to keep it for all lines, not just the first one and last one.

Comment: i am using java